# mixed timezone in DB, specify which columns are stored in UTC vs local timezone

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have to read from an external database, where some columns are in UTC and others are in a different timezone.
I know, bad DB design...

My model identifies the date columns in $casts, e.g.

```
protected $casts = [
 'exampleDbUtc' => 'datetime',
 'exampleDbLocal' => 'datetime',
]
```

I get

```
$item->exampleDbUtc
Carbon: 2020-11-20 20:30:00.0 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00) 
// in DB "20:30" -- should be treated as 21:30 local (or 20:30 UTC)

$item->exampleDbLocal
Carbon: 2020-11-20 21:30:00.0 Europe/Amsterdam (+01:00) 
// in DB "21:30" -- treated correctly
```

My config:
`env('config.app.timezone')` is set to `Europe/Amsterdam`

How do I specify / convert `$item->exampleDbUtc` so it is used as UTC (and shown correctly in local timezone)?

Answer (score 0):

In your Item model, you can put functions like this :

```
namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class Item extends Model
{
    public function getExampleDbUtcAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->setTimezone('UTC') : null;
    }

}
```

what this does is whenever you're getting the value of exampleDbUtc from database, it shows it in UTC. If you want to save it in UTC in database as well, you can add this function to your model:

```
public function setExampleDbUtcAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['exampleDbUtc'] = $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->setTimezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')  : null;

}
```

Comment: that does not work. It will result in exampleDbUtc: 19:30 UTC (should be 20:30 UTC, or 21:30 Europe/Amsterdam). It did put me on the right track though. This will work: `return Carbon::parse($value, 'UTC')->timezone(env('app.timezone'))`